Software update deleted printer drivers- Cant find
I have an older Canon Pixma mp210 printer. I tried to print and keep getting message "printing canceled, Cannot start printer."
Unable to locate drivers in printer setup.
I am able to scan from the printer.
UPDATE - VERSION 22.O4.5 of Ubuntu.
Tried loading gutenprint drivers in terminal. Got printer added showing gutenprint driver was added. When trying to print I get message "Could not start printer. Please check your printer configuration."

We can't help you, as you've provided no Ubuntu product or release details for us to provide specific help with. Why not tell us what you're using, are you hoping we guess?

This question is similar to: Canon MP210 printer: cannot install driver on Ubuntu 20.04. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: Canon printer drivers for Ubuntu 15.10. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

There is an open source initiative to provide drivers for openprinting / CUPS and your linux machine. You probably need to manually add the needed PPD config file for your printer
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mp610linux/
